# Knockout JS - Geting a modal popup to edit items

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

Im new to knockoutJS and really loving it. I'm trying to build something very similar to this http://jsfiddle.net/mac2000/N2zNk/light/. I tried copying the code and adapting it to my need. The problem with that is that I get my data from the server using $.getJSON it seems that the jsfiddle example was made for a different format of data which just confuses me.

So instead of asking for help to find the issue with my code I rather take a different approach. Hopefully you guys wont mind. Im starting from scratch and trying to learn each steps so I know what im doing.

Here is my code so far, this works great to simply display my data on my table.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function EmployeeModal() {
         var self = this;
         self.Employees = ko.observableArray([]);
         $.getJSON("../../../../_vti_bin/listData.svc/GDI_PROD_Incidents?$filter=ÉtatValue%20ne%20%27Fermé%27&$orderby=PrioritéValue desc",
             function (data) {
                 if (data.d.results) {
                     self.Employees(ko.toJS(data.d.results));
                 }
             }
       );
     }
     $(document).ready(function () {
         ko.applyBindings(new EmployeeModal());
     });

</script>
```

I made a template where each row has an edit button similar to the example but no fucntion of binding are done yet. Now what I would like to do is simply onlick pass the selected data to my modal and show my modal like so:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

This is the step im struggling the most with. Would any have any clear documentations for a noob or example, hints or any type of help I would take to get me in the right direction from here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assume you have them in a list like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: Employees">
     <li data-bind="text: fullName, click: showEmployee"/>
</ul>
```

What I'd recommend is to update your view model to look like this:

```
function EmployeeModal() {
     var self = this;
     self.Employees = ko.observableArray([]);

     self.currentEmployee = ko.observable(null);
     self.showEmployee = function(vm){
         self.currentEmployee(vm);
         $('#myModal').modal('show');
     };
     .... // rest of your view model here
}
```

The last piece will be using KO's [with binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html) to wrap your modal

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" data-bind="with: currentEmployee">
    <h1 data-bind="text: fullName"></h1>
</div>
```

What this does is listen for the click event on an individual element and automatically pass the view model bound to that element to the click handler you defined. We're then taking that view model, storing it in its own observable and then showing the modal like normal. The key here is the `with` binding which only executes when there's data stored in the observable, and also sets the context of all nested code to be the employee stored in `currentEmployee`.

There's a lot there if you're new, but using a `current` style observable to track individual data from a list is a great paradigm to use with Knockout = )

P.S.. the http://learn.knockoutjs.com/ tutorials are really great to work through if you've yet to do so.

Comment: Thats great, thank you so much for the details seems to make way more sense the way you done it. Im gonna give that a try.

Comment: Thank you so much. Have just spent the last hour trying the equivalent of self.currentEmployee = vm and nothing was showing inside the 'wtih'.